# Update Query I have two tables in a

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in a mysql database. macs and deviceinventory i want to updat macs table column name deviceid =1  but update those reords which not found in deviceinventory table column device id i use this query but it give error

```
UPDATE macs SET deviceid = 1 
WHERE deviceid = (SELECT deviceid FROM macs NOT IN (
                     SELECT * FROM deviceinventory.`deviceid`
                 )) ;
```

Comment: You put the `IN` statement in your sub-select query. Then, you should put `WHERE deviceid IN` instead of `WHERE deviceid =`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this:

```
UPDATE 
   macs 
SET 
   deviceid = 1 
WHERE 
   deviceid NOT IN 
     (SELECT deviceid FROM deviceinventory);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE macs 
SET deviceid = 1 
WHERE deviceid IN (
  SELECT deviceid 
  FROM macs 
  WHERE deviceid NOT IN (
      SELECT deviceid 
      FROM deviceinventory
  )
 ) ;
```

Comment: You Can't specify target table 'macs' for update from clause this error show :(